Error when trying to create app - Error creating the CFMessagePort needed to communicate with PPT
So recently I have been building an app to help hurt elderly when they are injured, and it makes use of bluetooth (for a physical SOS button) and location. However, I keep getting this error code: Error creating the CFMessagePort needed to communicate with PPT. Here is my code (Btw I am in Single View Code and not using storyboard):
import SwiftUI
import CoreBluetooth
import CallKit
import UIKit
import MessageUI
import CoreLocation

// Command Handler to manage different actions
class CommandHandler {
    static func initiateCall(phoneNumber: String) {
        if let url = URL(string: "tel://\(phoneNumber.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: ""))"),
           UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        }
    }
    
    static func sendSMS(phoneNumber: String, message: String, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        if MFMessageComposeViewController.canSendText() {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                NotificationCenter.default.post(
                    name: NSNotification.Name("SendSMS"),
                    object: nil,
                    userInfo: ["phoneNumber": phoneNumber, "message": message]
                )
            }
        } else {
            completion(false)
        }
    }
}

// Message Compose Delegate
class MessageDelegate: NSObject, MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate {
    func messageComposeViewController(_ controller: MFMessageComposeViewController,
                                    didFinishWith result: MessageComposeResult) {
        controller.dismiss(animated: true)
    }
}

// Bluetooth Manager class
class BluetoothManager: NSObject, ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    private var centralManager: CBCentralManager?
    private var peripheral: CBPeripheral?
    private var writeCharacteristic: CBCharacteristic?
    private var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    private var locationLabel = UILabel()
    
    @Published var connectionStatus = "Disconnected"
    @Published var receivedCommand = "No command received"
    @Published var isConnected = false
    @Published var lastCallTime: Date?
    @Published var lastSMSTime: Date?
    @Published var lastAction = "None"
    @Published var mylocation = CLLocation(latitude: 0, longitude: 0)
    
    // Configuration
    @Published var callPhoneNumber = ""  // Replace with call phone number
    @Published var smsPhoneNumber = ""   // Replace with SMS phone number
    let smsMessage = "Emergency Alert!"  // Default SMS message
    let commandToTriggerCall = "command: CMD001"  // Command for call
    let commandToTriggerSMS = "command: CMD002"   // Command for SMS
    let minimumActionInterval: TimeInterval = 60 // Minimum seconds between actions
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
    }
    
    func startScanning() {
        let services = [CBUUID(string: "FFE0")]
        centralManager?.scanForPeripherals(withServices: services, options: nil)
        connectionStatus = "Scanning..."
    }
    
    func connect(to peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        self.peripheral = peripheral
        self.peripheral?.delegate = self
        centralManager?.connect(peripheral, options: nil)
    }
    
    func setupLocationManager() {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let _ :CLLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation
        guard let location = locations.last else { return }
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        mylocation = CLLocation(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)
    }
        
    func disconnect() {
        if let peripheral = peripheral {
            centralManager?.cancelPeripheralConnection(peripheral)
        }
    }
    
    func setCallPhoneNumber(_ callPhoneNumber: String)
    {
        self.callPhoneNumber = callPhoneNumber
    }
    
    func handleReceivedCommand(_ command: String) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.receivedCommand = command
            let trimmedCommand = command.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
            
            // Check for call command
            if trimmedCommand == self.commandToTriggerCall {
                if let lastCall = self.lastCallTime {
                    let timeSinceLastCall = Date().timeIntervalSince(lastCall)
                    if timeSinceLastCall < self.minimumActionInterval {
                        return
                    }
                }
                self.lastCallTime = Date()
                self.lastAction = "Call initiated"
                CommandHandler.initiateCall(phoneNumber: self.callPhoneNumber)
            }
            
            // Check for SMS command
            if trimmedCommand == self.commandToTriggerSMS {
                if let lastSMS = self.lastSMSTime {
                    let timeSinceLastSMS = Date().timeIntervalSince(lastSMS)
                    if timeSinceLastSMS < self.minimumActionInterval {
                        return
                    }
                }
                self.lastSMSTime = Date()
                self.lastAction = "SMS initiated"
                CommandHandler.sendSMS(phoneNumber: self.smsPhoneNumber,
                                    message: self.smsMessage) { success in
                    if !success {
                        self.lastAction = "SMS failed - cannot send messages"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// BluetoothManager delegate extensions (same as before)
extension BluetoothManager: CBCentralManagerDelegate {
    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        switch central.state {
        case .poweredOn:
            startScanning()
        case .poweredOff:
            connectionStatus = "Bluetooth is Off"
        case .unauthorized:
            connectionStatus = "Bluetooth permission denied"
        default:
            connectionStatus = "Bluetooth unavailable"
        }
    }
    
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager,
                       didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral,
                       advertisementData: [String: Any],
                       rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
        self.connect(to: peripheral)
        centralManager?.stopScan()
    }
    
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager,
                       didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        connectionStatus = "Connected to \(peripheral.name ?? "HM-10")"
        isConnected = true
        peripheral.discoverServices(nil)
    }
    
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager,
                       didDisconnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral,
                       error: Error?) {
        connectionStatus = "Disconnected"
        isConnected = false
        startScanning()
    }
}

// Peripheral delegate extension (same as before)
extension BluetoothManager: CBPeripheralDelegate {
    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral,
                   didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {
        guard let services = peripheral.services else { return }
        for service in services {
            peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: service)
        }
    }
    
    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral,
                   didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService,
                   error: Error?) {
        guard let characteristics = service.characteristics else { return }
        
        for characteristic in characteristics {
            if characteristic.properties.contains(.notify) ||
               characteristic.properties.contains(.read) {
                peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: characteristic)
            }
            if characteristic.properties.contains(.write) {
                writeCharacteristic = characteristic
            }
        }
    }
    
    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral,
                   didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic,
                   error: Error?) {
        guard let data = characteristic.value,
              let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) else { return }
        
        handleReceivedCommand(string)
    }
}

// Main View
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var bluetoothManager = BluetoothManager()
    @State private var messageDelegate = MessageDelegate()
    @State private var phoneNo = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            // Status Header
            Text(bluetoothManager.connectionStatus)
                .padding()
                .background(bluetoothManager.isConnected ? Color.green : Color.red)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .cornerRadius(10)
            
            // Command Display
            VStack {
                Text("Received Command:")
                    .font(.headline)
                
                Text(bluetoothManager.receivedCommand)
                    .font(.title)
                    .padding()
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                
                Text("Last Action: \(bluetoothManager.lastAction)")
                    .font(.caption)
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
            }
            .padding()
            
            // Configuration Display
            VStack(spacing: 10) {
                Text("Configuration:")
                    .font(.headline)
                
                HStack {
                    Text("Call number:")
                    TextField("Enter phone number", text: $phoneNo)
                    //bluetoothManager.setCallPhoneNumber(phoneNo)
                }
                
                HStack {
                    Text("SMS number:")
                    TextField("Enter phone number", text: $phoneNo)
                    //let smsPhoneNumber = "\(phoneNo)"
                }
                
                Text("Commands:")
                    .font(.subheadline)
                Text("\(bluetoothManager.commandToTriggerCall) = Call")
                Text("\(bluetoothManager.commandToTriggerSMS) = SMS")
                
                Text("Location:")
                    .font(.subheadline)
                Text("Latitude: \(bluetoothManager.mylocation.coordinate.latitude)")
                Text("Longitude: \(bluetoothManager.mylocation.coordinate.longitude)")
            }
            .padding()
            .background(Color.blue.opacity(0.1))
            .cornerRadius(10)
            
            Spacer()
            
            // Connection Button
            if bluetoothManager.isConnected {
                Button(action: {
                    bluetoothManager.disconnect()
                }) {
                    Text("Not your watch? Press here to disconnect")
                        .padding()
                        .background(Color.red)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                }
            } else {
                Button(action: {
                    bluetoothManager.startScanning()
                }) {
                    Text("Start Scanning")
                        .padding()
                        .background(Color.blue)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
        .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: NSNotification.Name("SendSMS"))) { notification in
            if let phoneNumber = notification.userInfo?["phoneNumber"] as? String,
               let message = notification.userInfo?["message"] as? String {
                let messageVC = MFMessageComposeViewController()
                messageVC.messageComposeDelegate = messageDelegate
                messageVC.recipients = [phoneNumber]
                messageVC.body = message
                
                if let windowScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene,
                   let window = windowScene.windows.first,
                   let rootViewController = window.rootViewController {
                    rootViewController.present(messageVC, animated: true)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

    
    #Preview {
        ContentView()
    }



So what I expect is for a pop-up to show up when the app is one asking for the permissions for location. I did this with a previous app and it worked, but it didn't for this one. Thank you for helping in advance.

Where do you call setupLocationManager?

"Error creating the CFMessagePort needed to communicate with PPT" shows up even for a default new app. Other people are reporting that too. Nothing to do with bluetooth, etc..
